# IBM Maximo Asset Management, Display images inside lines

Tags: image, websphere, assets, maximo

The customer wants to be able to manage images within lines, for example, add an image to each task in the workorder, and this image also has to be able to visualize in the line and also from a birt report. I've tried using attachments but you can't view display attachments from a report because it is not a public url (for security reasons).

I know that Maximo allows you to manage images when you are in a main object like in asset application or person application. But is it possible to display it at a lower level (within each line) and display these images from a report and also in the same application.

IBM Maximo 7.6.1

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which Maximo version this relates to however in Maximo 7.6.0.0 you can add attachments to tasks associated with a workorder. The url below describes adding attached documents to objects that do not have that functionality out of the box.

[Maximo - Adding attached document functionality](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/adding-attached-document-functionality)